# T-test on pandas groupby().describe()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, scipy

I was trying to calculate t-test on the following table:

```
           XXX                                                                        YYY
          count        mean         std    min     25%     50%      75%      max      count        mean         std    min     25%     50%      75%      max    
Cluster                                                                               Cluster
Cluster 0  379.0  546.057942  728.552019  67.29  249.24  373.37  569.025  9772.17     Cluster 0  379.0  546.057942  728.552019  67.29  249.24  373.37  569.025  9772.17
Cluster 1  179.0  439.527765  363.232426  66.61  259.03  360.22  496.545  3702.97     Cluster 1  179.0  439.527765  363.232426  66.61  259.03  360.22  496.545  3702.97
```

I need t-test values for XXX and YYY and so on. Does anyone know how to calculate?

Thank you

Comment: Normally you run T-tests on your data, not the summary stats

Comment: @James that's a fair point. I am still exploring and trying to understand. Thank you for your answer!